# emailjs.send email works on debug mode only

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, synchronization, submit

I have an issue on the code below, it works only on debug mode (I guss it somthing reffers to synchron and unsynchron requests).

I'm trying to send an email when user press 'submit'.

another problem is that the console.log inside the .then doesnt print enything.

Hope you can help ,

Thank you!

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated')
                var radioValue = $('#paymentForm input:radio:checked').val()
                var orderNumber = generateId();
                var cName = $('#firstName').val() + " " + $('#lastName').val()
                var cEmail = $('#email').val()
                var cProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products") || "[]");
                console.log(cProducts);
                var templateParams = {
                    order_number: orderNumber,
                    customer_name: cName,
                    products: JSON.stringify(cProducts),
                    customer: cEmail
                };

                emailjs.send('gmail', 'orderconfirmation', templateParams)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
                        alert('Your mail is sent!');
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log('FAILED...', error);
                        alert('Oops... ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
            }, false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying add this before you closing the eventListener Parenthesis

```
event.preventDefault();
```